# How do I obfuscate the ids of my records in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, data-binding, obfuscation

I'm trying to figure out how to obfuscate the ids of my records in rails.

For example: a typical path might look like http://domain/records/1, so it's pretty easy for people to deduce how much traffic the site is getting if they just create a new record.

One solution that I've used is to hash the id with a salt, but since I'm not sure whether that function is bijective, I end up storing it in another column in my database and double check for uniqueness.

Another option I was thinking about was generating a random hash and storing that as another column. If it isn't unique ... just generate another one.

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use the built-in OpenSSL library to encrypt and decrypt your identifiers, that way you would only need to overwrite `to_param` on your models. You'll also need to use Base64 to convert the encrypted data into plain text. I would stick this in a module so it can be reused:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

module Obfuscate
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend self
  end

  def cipher
    OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
  end

  def cipher_key
    'blah!'
  end

  def decrypt(value)
    c = cipher.decrypt
    c.key = Digest::SHA256.digest(cipher_key)
    c.update(Base64.decode64(value.to_s)) + c.final
  end

  def encrypt(value)
    c = cipher.encrypt
    c.key = Digest::SHA256.digest(cipher_key)
    Base64.encode64(c.update(value.to_s) + c.final)
  end
end
```

So now your models would need to look something like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Obfuscate

  def to_param
    encrypt id
  end
end
```

Then in your controller when you need to find a record by the encrypted id, you would use something like this:

```
MyModel.find MyModel.decrypt(params[:id])
```

If you're looking to encrypt/decrypt ids ***without*** storing them in the database, this is probably the easiest way to go.

Comment: This is awesome :) Is there any way to get rid of the extra "==" at the end of the encrypted string?

Comment: That's part of the Base64 encryption so it is needed to decrypt the id. You could remove it in the `encrypt` method and add it back in the `decrypt` method, but that might be more prone to error (as I'm not sure if Base64 *always* includes the `==` at the end of the string).

Comment: Base64 pads out with `=` if the number of bits being encoded doesn't match up precisely. There will be zero, one, or two of them depending on the length of the input.

Comment: This could produce an id with a '/' in it that would break your routes. (and probably some other combinations of characters).  Use `urlsafe_encode64` and `urlsafe_decode64` instead

Comment: This solution worked for me. I just added a simple modification so that it has more scalability. Within model User.rb, I provided action,   def self.find(id);; id=decrypt(id);; super;; end;; Then, we just use User.find(params[:id]) as usual. P/S: I cannot enter for new line, so that I use (;;) instead on the code above.

Comment: @datnt What do you mean you provided an action. I'm trying to make this work inside my models rb file.

Comment: @Anthony I think he just means he overrode the `find` method in his User class.

Comment: @Anthony: siannopollo is right. I override method "find" for class User.rb. Just open your model file (e.g: User.rb), and define a new method just as I mentioned in the previous comment.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of numeric ids, use some kind of friendly url or human readable slug. There are **[lots of tools](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_permalinks___slugs)** to choose from in this department. Not only are they more friendly to your users, but well chosen slugs can give a nice advantage with search engines.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a gem that keeps it numeric, requires no database migrations, and no routing changes: https://github.com/namick/obfuscate_id

---

I've found that this gem doesn't work in concert with some other gems, notably paper_trail. This is because of the way it replaces the `find` method, and paper_trail causes `find` to be called with the actual record id.

So I've been using the gem's "scatter_swap" functionality, but not the rest of it. Here's the model:

```
require 'obfuscate_id/scatter_swap'

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  # This is a random number that, if changed, will invalidate all existing URLs. Don't change it!
  @@obfuscate_spin = # random number here, which is essentially the encryption key

  ##
  # Generate URL parameter to be used in the URL as the "id"
  def to_param
    # Use the obfuscate_id gem's class to "spin" the id into something obfuscated
    spun_id = ScatterSwap.hash(self.id, @@obfuscate_spin)

    # Throw any additional attributes in here that are to be included in the URL.
    "#{spun_id} #{name}".parameterize
  end

  def self.find_by_slug!(slug)
    spun_id = slug[/^[0-9]+/]
    begin
      find_by_id! ScatterSwap.reverse_hash(spun_id, @@obfuscate_spin)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, "Couldn't find matching Page."
    end
  end
end
```

And in the controller:

```
class PagesController < InheritedResources::Base
  # Find the page using its URL slug
  before_filter :find_page, except: [:index, :create, :new]

  def find_page
    @page = Page.find_by_slug! params[:id]

    # If the URL doesn't match exactly, and this is a GET.
    # We'll redirect to the new, correct URL, but if this is a non-GET, let's let them finish their request instead.
    if params[:id] != @page.to_param && request.get?
      redirect_to url_for({ id: @page.to_param }), status: 301
    end
  end
end
```

As an alternative to the redirection that takes place there, you could simply include a canonical URL in the page. The redirection has the bug of ignoring any query parameters in the URL. This was not a problem for my project, as I didn't have any. But a canonical URL would be better.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty easy to generate unique random identifiers for your records either using a randomized string generator or a simple call to `Digest::SHA1.hexdigest` which produces reasonably random and cryptographically unique results.

For instance, you can create a secondary column called `ident` or `unique_id` that stores your public identifiers. You can then over-write `to_param` to use this instead:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :assign_ident

  def self.from_param(ident)
    find_by_ident(ident)
  end

  def to_param
    self.ident
  end

protected
  def assign_ident
    self.ident = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(SecureRandom.random_number(1<<256).to_s)
  end
end
```

Theoretically there is a chance of collision on SHA1 but the odds are so astronomically low you're more liable to have a software crash because of a memory error or hardware malfunction. You can test this to see if it suits your needs by generating a few billion identities to see if they ever collide, which they shouldn't. A 256-bit random number should provide a sufficient amount of data for the SHA1 algorithm to chew on.

Comment: I'm glad that great minds think alike. That's basically what I was trying to do.

Comment: I think OP wanted to be able to decrypt the obfuscated result as well without relying on a lookup.

Answer (score 4):

After reading through [@siannopollo's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9305230/429758), I created a Gem based on the idea of his post (but with some improvements): https://github.com/pencil/encrypted_id

Answer (score 0):

Just because it hasn't been mentioned here: You could simply use UUIDs ([wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier))

There are multiple ways of using UUID as primary keys in Rails, depending on your Rails version and database engine. It's easy to find.

Just as a possibility, in case you depend too much on your existing integer primary key, you can also just add a UUID to your table and make your model use it automatically when it comes to generating URLs by overwriting `Model#to_param` [more details in the docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Integration/ClassMethods/to_param)